# How can I force a dependency to reload in torch after recompiling it?

Tags: lua, torch

I am working on a torch package that is a luarock. During testing I want to  `require "mypackage"` and get the latest code without exiting my `th` session.

However, as I understand it, `require` caches the loaded packages so they're not loaded a second time. The [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html) seems to suggest that there is global variable `_LOADED` that stores this cached information and I could simply set the value for my package to `nil`:

```
_LOADED['mypackage'] = nil
```

However, in torch, there doesn't seem to be a `_LOADED` global, even after I have required some packages.

Thoughts?

Comment: try `package.loaded`

Comment: @hjpotter92, hm...setting the entry for `mypackage` to nil and doing another `require` does indeed require the package again, however, inside my package I do additional requires to load individual pieces and those are still cached. I guess I could write a `reload` method as part of my package that will remove all of its entries from `packages.loaded` and then re-require itself. Or maybe I shouldn't do requires inside my package to pull in other parts of itself?

Comment: use `local pkg = require 'pkg'` for the additional packages put inside `mypackage`.